# Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='identify_email']"}

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='identify_email']"}
```

Even-though the selector that i have written is correct. I have checked it using console. Any idea how to resolve this?

```
package lbw;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Locators {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
    "C:\\Users\\vicky\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Forgotten account?")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'identify_email\']")).sendKeys("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='Search']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='send_email']")).click(); /*im getting error in this line. Im try to select a radio. */
    System.out.println("Completed");
}
```

}

Comment: Why use `xpath` when you can use `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with adding **implicity wait** or **WebDriver wait**. Here is example of second:

```
public static void waitForElementPresent(this IWebElement element)
        {
            try
            {
                wait.Until(driver => element.Displayed);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Assert.Fail("The element not found. The exception: \n" + e.GetType());
            }
        }
```